# How to add custom link to menu in wordpress programmatically?

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to add a custom link to the main menu on my local site (wordpress with woocommerce and storefront as theme) in my plugin. 
I'm using the `wp_nav_menu_items` but this doesn't add append new item to the menu on front-end.
the code is:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', function($items, $args) {
        //I tried to echo statement here
        // but it never displays 
        $link = '<li>Login</li>';

        echo $items.$link; //echo for testing
}, 20, 2);
```

Answer (score 4):

You must return the value of a filter instead of echoing it...

Example:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', function($items, $args) {

        $link = '<li>Login</li>';

        return $items . $link;

}, 20, 2);
```

The above will effect all menus however, instead use the `$args` variable to conditionally modify a specific menu only or use `"wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items"` which will only operatae on a specific menu, where `$menu->slug` is the key value passed to `register_nav_menus` or `register_nav_menu`

Recommended reading:

- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L418
- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L429
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu

Comment: I tried this but still its not added.

Comment: Then show what you tried.  We can't help unless you show specifically what you have done.